# Simplest way to create a simple parse in Java

Tags: parsing, cup

I know about CUP or javaCC or some other parser generators,

but I want to add the ability to understand a simple language to my project, without the need to configure a complex tool as CUP.

The language is something a little too complicated to be parsed with regular expressions, since I want to use operators:

```
|| && ( ) [ ]
```

Comment: You could try to write a recursive descent parser: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser

Comment: It would be interesting, but probably longer than using an already made parser and more bug prone...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functionality is provided for Python by a library called [PyParse](http://www.ccp4.ac.uk/dist/checkout/pyparsing-2.0.1/examples/0README.html). Probably the library can be integrated using Jython.

Comment: Best to install using `python -m pip install pyparsing` to get the latest released version.

Answer (score 0):

The JRE comes with a javascript engine embedded. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngine.html

Also there is tutorial here -> 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/